# Need help installing a package

Tags: installation, 10.04, apt, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file)

So I want to install the zathura package:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/zathura

Unfortunately it isn't as easy as sudo apt-get install and my resident linux geek has gone to sleep.

Following the link above it is possible to find some .tar.gz archives, one of which (zathura_0.0.8.5.orig.tar.gz) actually includes a README and a make file. Nevertheless whoever wrote those assumes a basic level of competence that I do not have. In particular I have no idea how to check whether I meet the stated requirements, and what to do if I do not. (running make install produces a bunch of errors, so I assume I don't have the required dependencies.)

Still a beginner so I usually need step by step instructions to install anything.

In a response to comments below it is important I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - the Lucid Lynx. Apparently the package in question is incorporated in the "Ubuntu Software Centre" for newer versions of Ubuntu.

I also appreciate this post is getting to localized. Nevertheless I just want to thank everyone who answered/commented. Between this discussion and the other post ([How to install a .tar.gz file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file)) I am close to having worked out how to compile the package from source.

Comment: I had had a look at the above post, but did not find it terribly insightful. It talks about the right topic but in insufficient detail.

Comment: Anything "insightful" is going to be horribly package specific and not useful to other users...hence closable as too localised.  I take your point, but if you want to compile from source it WILL take practice or reading.  It's not checkboxes.

Comment: Please edit your question detailing what version of ubuntu you have, thanks.

Comment: How about you just wait for your "resident Linux geek" to wake up? ;)

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for answering my own question as well as the fact that it was probably to localized.

The one bit of information I needed and wasn't able to find on that other post ([How to install a .tar.gz file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file)), which might be of general interest, is that when a README file in a .tar.gz file containing the source code for some package lists it's pre-requisites/dependencies you need the developer version of those packages. For example, I needed `libpoppler-glib-dev` (in Synaptic) rather than `libpoppler-glib4` which I already had. Threw me off.

Once I had the right packages it was as easy as running `make` and then `sudo make install` (or `checkinstall`) while in the extracted folder containing the package.

Comment: It's not bad to answer your own question. It's [most excellent](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Furthermore, this questions is unlikely to be too localized, though it may be considered a duplicate of [the more general question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file). (Nobody has voted to close as too-localized.) If we do dupe it to that question, you might consider posting this valuable information about `README`s there.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package using Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic (this will install the prebuilt application)

Comment: If it was that easy I would have done it already.

Comment: @Psachnodaimonia It's in software center for 12.04...so yes, it is that easy

Comment: So that's where I went wrong: I don't have 12.04...

Comment: There are also versions for Natty and Oneiric (and there will be one for Quantal). What goes wrong when you try to install it with Synaptic? Installing from a tar.gz file is much more complicated.